# OAuth 2.0 token using Jmeter

Tags: oauth-2.0, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to setup API calls for performance testing using `Jmeter 3.0`
As a prerequisite i need to create `OAuth 2.0` token for authentication purposes.

So I am trying to setup the token generation mechanism in `Jmeter` itself.

`Jmeter` has `OAuth` sampler but it doesn't state whether it uses `OAuth 2.0` or `HMAC SHA256` algorithm .

Question is **what is the best process for generating the token?**

I have browsed `Blazemeter` blog but it talks about making use of Google API for generating the `HMAC` key.